# ONVIF PullMessages Fault

Tags: onvif

I understand that cameras that do not have WSBaseNotification feature do not support push-style notifications (Notify), so I have to do the pull-style way (CreatePullPointSubscription and PullMessages).

First I obtain the SubscriptionReference address from CreatePullPointSubscription and pass it to the "To" address in PullMessages. This has succeeded with one of the three cameras I have tested but failed with the other.

Here is a sample of response for CreatePullPointSubscription:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Header><wsa5:MessageID>urn:uuid:18764990-3fd8-4175-b074-bfdd6816d5a2</
wsa5:MessageID><wsa5:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:1adbe268-c822-eb58-8560-b07639671351</wsa5:RelatesTo><wsa5:To SOAP-
ENV:mustUnderstand="true">http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</wsa5:To><wsa5:Action SOAP-
ENV:mustUnderstand="true">http://www.onvif.org/ver10/events/wsdl/EventPortType/
CreatePullPointSubscriptionResponse</wsa5:Action></SOAP-ENV:Header><SOAP-
ENV:Body><tev:CreatePullPointSubscriptionResponse><tev:SubscriptionReference><wsa5:Address>http://172.22.22.35:80/
onvif/device_service?Idx=0</wsa5:Address></tev:SubscriptionReference><wsnt:CurrentTime>2015-11-26T17:05:55Z</
wsnt:CurrentTime><wsnt:TerminationTime>2038-01-19T03:14:07Z</wsnt:TerminationTime></
tev:CreatePullPointSubscriptionResponse></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

And PulMessagesRequest:

```
<s:Header><wsa:To>http://172.22.22.35:80/onvi /device_service?Idx=0</wsa:To><wsse:Security><wsse:UsernameToken>
<wsse:Username>admin</wsse:Username><wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-
profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">XWhDcuw3cztspGCLlpQfVaqM1mU=</wsse:Password><wsse:Nonce>NTY1NmNiODFjYTk4MWZlNjFmNDA=</wsse:Nonce>
<wsu:Created>2015-11-26T09:06:09Z</wsu:Created></wsse:UsernameToken></wsse:Security></s:Header><s:Body><tev:PullMessages>
<tev:Timeout>PT5S</tev:Timeout><tev:MessageLimit>2</tev:MessageLimit></tev:PullMessages></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

And PullMessagesResponse:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Header><wsa5:To SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="true">http://172.22.22.35:80/onvif
/device_service?Idx=0</wsa5:To></SOAP-ENV:Header><SOAP-ENV:Body><SOAP-ENV:Fault><SOAP-ENV:Code><SOAP-ENV:Value>SOAP-ENV:Sender</SOAP-ENV:Value>
<SOAP-ENV:Subcode><SOAP-ENV:Value>InvalidArgVal</SOAP-ENV:Value></SOAP-ENV:Subcode></SOAP-ENV:Code><SOAP-ENV:Reason><SOAP-ENV:Text 
xml:lang="en">InvalidArgVal</SOAP-ENV:Text></SOAP-ENV:Reason><SOAP-
ENV:Detail>There is no subscribe.</SOAP-ENV:Detail></SOAP-ENV:Fault></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [ONVIF core specs](http://www.onvif.org/specs/core/ONVIF-Core-Specification-v261.pdf):

> **9.1.2 Pull messages**
>
> The device shall provide the following PullMessages command for all SubscriptionManager **endpoints returned by** the CreatePullPointSubscription command.

Therefore you need to pull the messages from the address returned int the `CreatePullPointSubscription` . Populating the `wsa5:To` field in the body of the request but using the URL of the event service is in general not enough.

You posted only the body of the soap requests and not the head, thus it's impossible to check the URL you're using.